# Alternative to DataSourceStreamingDataHandler for MTOM testing

Tags: java, mtom, sun

In a JUnit test I am using the class `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.DataSourceStreamingDataHandler` which is bad because it is an internal class and Maven refuses to compile my JUnit tests even with `-DskipTests` flag.

My JUnit test is:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    ClassToTest tom = new ClassToTest();
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/myXMLFile.xml");
    File file = new File(url.getPath());
    DataSource dataSource = new FileDataSource(file);
    DataHandler dataHandler = new DataSourceStreamingDataHandler(dataSource);
    MyJAXBObject list = tom.methodToTest(dataHandler);
    for( JAXBTransazioneICT t : lista.getListaTransazioniICT() ){
        LOG.debug(t.toString());
    }
}
```

Is there a good alternative to this class? If not, how can I compile my Maven project?

Comment: What do you use this class for?

Comment: @Tichodroma I am testing MTOM web services. I have posted my JUnit case.

Comment: So you are looking for an implementation of [`javax.activation.DataHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/DataHandler.html)? How about mocking this interface?

Comment: @Tichodroma, yes, that's an option. But I think that finding a working alternative can be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative I found is `org.apache.axiom.attachments.ConfigurableDataHandler` from Axiom API.

The maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```